# Can I hide all posts from Tumblr's main blog while keeping them unhidden from their routed pages?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I'm trying to figure out how I can keep my all of my posts off of my homepage without hiding them from my secondary pages......

Here's what I'm working with:

http://brewerstl.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following should work:

```
{block:IndexPage}

{block:TagPage}
<p> This will be printed on any page `tagged/xxx`</p>

{block:Text}
<!-- Add your post type loops here -->
{/block:Text}

{/block:TagPage}

{/block:IndexPage}
```

To summarise. The template returns no posts for the indexpage (homepage) and returns what ever post types you state on the tagged pages.