# difficulty applying a tumblr CSS

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to block all posts from my home page and I have the code to do it but I don't know how to make it work.

Any help would be great!

```
{block:IndexPage}
<p> This will be printed on the homepage </p> 
{/block:IndexPage}

{block:TagPage}
{block:IndexPage}
<p> This will be printed on any page `tagged/xxx`</p>

{block:Text}
<!-- Add your post type loops here -->
{/block:Text}

{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:TagPage}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `{block:TagPage}` and `{block:IndexPage}` rendering at the same time. Remove the IndexPage block from your TagPage block.

Comment: The confusion is my fault. I updated my original answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581570/can-i-hide-all-posts-from-tumblrs-main-blog-while-keeping-them-unhidden-from-th